# (Pattern) matching against strings in Scala

Tags: string, scala, pattern-matching

I want to compare a given string to a given set of other strings. Instead of using a series of `if`s I went for the more concise pattern matching way, and intuitively wrote:

```
val s = "match"

val s1 = "not match"
val s2 = "not really a match"
val s3 = "match"

s match {
  case s1 => println("Incorrect match 1")
  case s2 => println("Incorrect match 2")
  case s3 => println("Match")
  case _ => println("Another incorrect match")
}
```

Which, surprisingly to me, resulted in:

```
Incorrect match 1
```

And my compiler warning that beyond `case s2 =>...` my code is unreachable. Why doesn't my approach work? And how can I "match" against a string?

Comment: Do you require pattern matching?

Comment: Yes, the example is simplified to bring my problem across.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This **lowercase** variable with **pattern match** in **Scala**, it will be thought it's a **new temp variable**. that's caused your code will output `Incorrect match 1`. so you can use an `identifier` to encode your variable to match their value, like:

```
  s match {
    case `s1` => println("Incorrect match 1")
    case `s2` => println("Incorrect match 2")
    case `s3` => println("Match")
```

or you can update your variable name to **uppercase**, like to: `S1`, `S2`, `S3`